# How to download the cuDNN straight from nvidia website to my linux instance on GCP

Tags: tensorflow, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, cudnn

I want to install tensorflow-gpu on my linux machine on google cloud platform. I am not using an deep learning vm gcp provide. So I installed anaconda on my linux instance and now i want to install tensorflow. I already installed nvidia drivers and cuda. They can be downloaded straight in to the cloud instances. But for cuDNN I have to download it into my local machine and then upoad it into the cloud instance. Is there a way to download that file directly from nvidia site to my cloud instance? Thank you

EDIT

---

```
 CUDNN_URL="developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v5.1/cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz" 
 wget -c ${CUDNN_URL}
```

Using these lines of commands we can directly download cudnnv5.1 and I have seen the links for version 6.5 as well. I tried the same link by putting the version I want but it did not work. Anyone knows a way to use this CUDNN_URL to directly download cudnn v7.1 or higher directly using wget or curl but not logging into the an Nvidia account?

Comment: What you are missing in your link is the full version. It was introduced with version 7.2.1.
Versions 7.2.1 and later: developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.2.1/cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38.tgz
Versions before that had: developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.1.4/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz

Comment: For the complete explanation, please have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

There was a change in the naming convention of cuDNN archives.

Since version 7.2.1, NVIDIA added the full version number into the archive name instead of the previously used short one.

That means that the resulting download link for 7.2.1 is:
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.2.1/cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38.tgz
instead of,
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.2.1/cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.tgz

You can follow this pattern:

```
VERSION_FULL="8.1.0.77"
VERSION="${VERSION_FULL%.*}"
CUDA_VERSION="11.2"
OS_ARCH="linux-x64"
CUDNN_URL="https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v${VERSION}/cudnn-${CUDA_VERSION}-${OS_ARCH}-v${VERSION_FULL}.tgz" 
wget -c ${CUDNN_URL}
```

The resulting link would be:
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v8.1.0/cudnn-10.2-linux-x64-v8.1.0.77.tgz

Comment: You, sir, are a master!

Comment: Just in case, this is mine latest for Windows: https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/secure/8.3.1/local_installers/11.5/cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.3.1.22_cuda11.5-archive.zip

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to have a developer account to get cuDNN there are no direct links to download files.

**As a workaround** you can download cuDNN and other software to your local machine and then follow documentation [Transferring files to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) to copy files to your VM instance:

[image: transfer]

For example, if you use Windows I'd recommend you to use [WinSCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp) to copy files to your VM.

In addition, have a look at this article [Deep Learning environment setup on Ubuntu(16.04) | CUDA, cuDNN, OpenCV(3.x), TensorFlow, Keras](https://medium.com/@anujonthemove/deep-learning-environment-setup-on-ubuntu-16-04-83078e1cba1f).

Comment: yeah that's how I uploaded cuda and drivers using scp command. And I think I got the asnwer for what I wanted. thanks

Comment: There are direct links but not always publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This method works up to CUDNN v8.8**, no longer works for v8.9+.

Even simpler (and better):

Just browse https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/ and grab the link (source or installer package). The URL pattern is not very consistent across different versions.

e.g., If you need CUDNN v8.7 on a Linux x86_64:

- https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v8.7.0/
- https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v8.7.0/local_installers/11.8/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.7.0.84_cuda11-archive.tar.xz

Comment: This doesn't work for 8.9 onwards.

Comment: Is there a CLI-only method that does work for newer releases ?

Answer (score 0):

If your really concerned about(I was) data to download cuda and cudnn files to your local machine and then upload it to the gcp instance. You can set up an GUI for your GCP instance in no time. check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3RnnmcNI_E or any vnc server tutorial. After that you can directly download any file from using a web browser.