# How to create a Deep Learning VM instance with ubuntu OS installed in GCP?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I need a **quick** GCP instance with GPUs, and **tensorflow 1.15-gpu preinstalled** and **ubuntu** as the operating  system. I tried creating a Deep Learning VM instance from the marketplace. I can get GPUs and tensorflow 1.15-gpu preinstalled but I am getting Debian as my operating system by default. They do not provide an option to choose an operating system when I deploy the instance. Is there a way to create such an instance with above requirements? (Solution without using Deep Learning VM solutions is also fine)

#### Update

[I tried this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60849474/7876086) to manually install TensorFlow, CUDA and cudnn.

Comment: This link may be of some help, it describes how to create a VM for Deep Learning using Ubuntu 16.04. With a little modification you should be able to adapt it for your needs : 
https://medium.com/giscle/setting-up-a-google-cloud-instance-for-deep-learning-d182256cb894

Comment: You can install TensorFlow from NVIDIA from GCP marketplace.It will install TensoFlow on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
Please review tensorflow documentation [1] which outlines how to Install TensorFlow with pip.
 

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, Please check [this](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/nvidia-ngc-public/nvidia_gpu_cloud_image) GCP marketplace (Or) as an alternative user can create custom VM instance in GCP. Create instance page -> Select "Change" Boot Disk and Choose operating system as Ubuntu from the dropdown list.

Comment: @DerekFender Thank you. I tried that but seems(tried) like we cannot directly download cudnn from the nvidia website (check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850728/7876086) If there's a way please do lmk.

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors Your solution does not let me create less than 8cpus. and less than 30GB RAM. Secondly for custom vms we don't get tf preinstalled.

Comment: Yes, TF need to be install in Custom VM's.